# Array stringified but not operational in TypeScript / javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

A string is generated with the correct structure including array. I can navigate through the JSON in sites like http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

But when I try to access the array, the array itself is null.

Here is my case:

First the interfaces:

```
export interface IPlayerJSON {
    idPlayer: number,
    name: string;
    email: string,
    arrayAvatar: Array<IAvatarJSON>,
};

export interface IAvatarJSON {
    idAvatar: number,
    nickName: string,
    original: boolean,
    signature: string,
};
```

and then the overridden method

```
public toJSON(): IPlayerJSON {
        let json: IPlayerJSON;
        json = {idPlayer: this.idPlayer, email: this.email, name: this.name, avatarOriginal: this.avatarOriginal.toJSON(),
               arrayAvatar: []}
        for (let r of this.arrayAvatar) {
            json.arrayAvatar.push(r.toJSON());
        };
        return json;
    };
```

Avatar has a modified toJSON as well. As I said, the JSON.stringify generates a correct and navigable JSON.

When I try to rehydrate:

```
public static playerRehydrate(json: IPlayerJSON): Player {
        let player : Player = new Player(null, null, null);
        console.log('JSON ', json); // perfect, with array
        player.setEmail(json.email);
        player.setPlayerID(json.idPlayer);
        player.setName(json.name);
        console.log('Array Avatar ', json.arrayAvatar);
        for (let r of json.arrayAvatar) { // throw error, no lenght of undefined
            player.addAvatar(RehydrateService.avatarRehydrate(r));
        };
        return player;
    };
```

json.arrayAvatar is null, and I can't interact through it.

Any tips? Thanks

Comment: Would be helpful to look at the output json, and what you get from the log line `Array Avatar`.

Comment: `IPlayerJSON` doesn't have `avatarOriginal` but you are adding it in `toJSON`

Answer (score 0):

ok, I missed a step in the process.

The correct is:

```
let player: Player;
let txt: string = JSON.stringify(player); // here all the toJSON() chain will be called
let playerJSON: IPlayerJSON = JSON.parse(txt); // <-- here is the missing code
player = playerRehydrate(playerJSON); // now player has state and behaviour
```

Comment: Yeah, you didn't mention anything using `JSON.stringify` in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted [works on its own in the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IPlayerJSON%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20idPlayer%3A%20number%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20email%3A%20string%2C%0A%20%20%20%20arrayAvatar%3A%20Array%3CIAvatarJSON%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20IAvatarJSON%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20idAvatar%3A%20number%2C%0A%20%20%20%20nickName%3A%20string%2C%0A%20%20%20%20original%3A%20boolean%2C%0A%20%20%20%20signature%3A%20string%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Avatar%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor(%0A%20%20%20%20public%20idAvatar%3A%20number%2C%0A%20%20%20%20public%20nickName%3A%20string%2C%0A%20%20%20%20public%20original%3A%20boolean%2C%0A%20%20%20%20public%20signature%3A%20string%0A%20%20)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20public%20toJSON()%3A%20IAvatarJSON%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20%7B%20idAvatar%2C%20nickName%2C%20original%2C%20signature%20%7D%20%3D%20this%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20idAvatar%2C%20nickName%2C%20original%2C%20signature%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Player%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor(%0A%20%20%20%20public%20idPlayer%3A%20number%2C%0A%20%20%20%20public%20email%3A%20string%2C%0A%20%20%20%20public%20name%3A%20string%2C%0A%20%20%20%20public%20avatarOriginal%3A%20Avatar%20%3D%20null%2C%0A%20%20%20%20public%20arrayAvatar%3A%20Avatar%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20)%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20public%20setEmail(email%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.email%20%3D%20email%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20public%20setPlayerID(idPlayer%3A%20number)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.idPlayer%20%3D%20idPlayer%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20public%20setName(name%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20name%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20public%20addAvatar(avatar%3A%20Avatar)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.arrayAvatar.push(avatar)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20public%20toJSON()%3A%20IPlayerJSON%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20json%3A%20IPlayerJSON%3B%0A%20%20%20%20json%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20idPlayer%3A%20this.idPlayer%2C%20email%3A%20this.email%2C%20name%3A%20this.name%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20avatarOriginal%3A%20this.avatarOriginal.toJSON()%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20arrayAvatar%3A%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20r%20of%20this.arrayAvatar)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20json.arrayAvatar.push(r.toJSON())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20json%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20RehydrateService%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20playerRehydrate(json%3A%20IPlayerJSON)%3A%20Player%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20player%3A%20Player%20%3D%20new%20Player(null%2C%20null%2C%20null)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('JSON%20in%20rehydrate'%2C%20json)%3B%20%2F%2F%20perfect%2C%20with%20array%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20player.setEmail(json.email)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20player.setPlayerID(json.idPlayer)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20player.setName(json.name)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('Array%20Avatar%20in%20rehydrate'%2C%20json.arrayAvatar)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20r%20of%20json.arrayAvatar)%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20throw%20error%2C%20no%20lenght%20of%20undefined%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20player.addAvatar(RehydrateService.avatarRehydrate(r))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20player%3B%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20public%20static%20avatarRehydrate(json%3A%20IAvatarJSON)%3A%20Avatar%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Avatar(json.idAvatar%2C%20json.nickName%2C%20json.original%2C%20json.signature)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20player%3A%20Player%20%3D%20new%20Player(1%2C%20%22%40%22%2C%20%22a%22%2C%0A%20%20new%20Avatar(2%2C%20%22b%22%2C%20true%2C%20%22bb%22)%2C%0A%20%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Avatar(3%2C%20%22c%22%2C%20false%2C%20%22cc%22)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Avatar(4%2C%20%22d%22%2C%20false%2C%20%22dd%22)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Avatar(5%2C%20%22e%22%2C%20false%2C%20%22ee%22)%0A%20%20%5D%0A)%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(%22player%20source%3A%22%2C%20player)%0Aconsole.log(%22player%20to%20JSON%20result%3A%22%2C%20player.toJSON())%0Aconsole.log(%22rehydrate%20player%20JSON%20result%3A%22%2C%20RehydrateService.playerRehydrate(player.toJSON()))), so your problem must be in some other code somewhere else. (Couldn't post as comment because playground link with source code is too long.)

```
interface IPlayerJSON {
    idPlayer: number,
    name: string;
    email: string,
    arrayAvatar: Array<IAvatarJSON>,
}

interface IAvatarJSON {
    idAvatar: number,
    nickName: string,
    original: boolean,
    signature: string,
}

class Avatar {
  constructor(
    public idAvatar: number,
    public nickName: string,
    public original: boolean,
    public signature: string
  ) {

  }
  public toJSON(): IAvatarJSON {
    const { idAvatar, nickName, original, signature } = this;
    return { idAvatar, nickName, original, signature };
  }
}

class Player {
  constructor(
    public idPlayer: number,
    public email: string,
    public name: string,
    public avatarOriginal: Avatar = null,
    public arrayAvatar: Avatar[] = []
  ) {

  }
  public setEmail(email: string) {
    this.email = email;
  }
  public setPlayerID(idPlayer: number) {
    this.idPlayer = idPlayer;
  }
  public setName(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  public addAvatar(avatar: Avatar) {
    this.arrayAvatar.push(avatar);
  }
  public toJSON(): IPlayerJSON {
    let json: IPlayerJSON;
    json = {
      idPlayer: this.idPlayer, email: this.email, name: this.name,
      // avatarOriginal: this.avatarOriginal.toJSON(), 
      arrayAvatar: []
    }
    for (let r of this.arrayAvatar) {
      json.arrayAvatar.push(r.toJSON());
    };
    return json;
  }
}

class RehydrateService {
    public static playerRehydrate(json: IPlayerJSON): Player {
      let player: Player = new Player(null, null, null);
      console.log('JSON in rehydrate', json); // perfect, with array
      player.setEmail(json.email);
      player.setPlayerID(json.idPlayer);
      player.setName(json.name);
      console.log('Array Avatar in rehydrate', json.arrayAvatar);
      for (let r of json.arrayAvatar) { // throw error, no lenght of undefined
          player.addAvatar(RehydrateService.avatarRehydrate(r));
      };
      return player;
  };
  public static avatarRehydrate(json: IAvatarJSON): Avatar {
    return new Avatar(json.idAvatar, json.nickName, json.original, json.signature);
  }
}

const player: Player = new Player(1, "@", "a",
  new Avatar(2, "b", true, "bb"),
  [
    new Avatar(3, "c", false, "cc"),
    new Avatar(4, "d", false, "dd"),
    new Avatar(5, "e", false, "ee")
  ]
);

console.log("player source:", player)
console.log("player to JSON result:", player.toJSON())
console.log("rehydrate player JSON result:", RehydrateService.playerRehydrate(player.toJSON()))
```

Output from last log statement after toJSON and rehydrate includes the avatar array:

[image]

An this shows you can iterate over the avatar array:

```
RehydrateService.playerRehydrate(player.toJSON()).arrayAvatar.forEach(avatar => console.log(avatar))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but if you try to navigate through the array it will give you an error. So you need to add the JSON.parse in the result of rehydrate method.

Comment: Not so, at least not with the posted code. I see you added an answer where you included `JSON.stringify` not shown in your original question.